# Django:How i can call the values of the fields of a form that i want to display properly when i want to generate a pdf printout

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Hi stackoverflow team;

Am newbie on django ,I Hope i can find solution or someone can help me because am really stuck on , I have spent the whole day searching without reaching my goal;

I want to generate a printout after fill out a form , this form contain the fields "longeur", "hauteur", "element", the user will fill out this form then he will click on a button to display the  "moment" and the "area" that would be calculated automatically and be displayed under the form. but on the **printout** I would for now just  display the values typed by the user in the field **"longuer" and "hauteur"**

Here is the story of my code;

I have a the model class in **models.py** of the form(formulaire):

```
class Forms(models.Model): 
    element = models.CharField(verbose_name=" Component ", max_length=60, default="e1")
    hauteur = models.FloatField(verbose_name=" Height ")
    longuer = models.FloatField(verbose_name=" Length between posts ")
```

in the **views.py**: I have defined the function "forms_render_pdf_view" for generating the pdf where I have passed the fields of the form("longeur" and "hauteur" to the dictionary "context") that i want their values to be displayed on my pdf printout.

```
def forms_render_pdf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
   template_path = 'pages/generate_pdf.html'
   context = {'longuer':request.GET.get('longuer'), 'hauteur':request.GET.get('hauteur')}
   response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="report.pdf"'
   template = get_template(template_path)
   html = template.render(context)
   pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(
      html, dest=response)
   if pisa_status.err:
      return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
   return response
```

the **forms.py**:

```
class FormsCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Forms
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and here is the the html file to render it to pdf:(`generate_pdf.html`) where i have called "hauteur" and "longeur" to display their values in the pdf.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body style="font-size: 18px;"">
    <div style="padding: 3rem;" class="container">
        <h1>Hauteur:</h1>
        <p>{{ hauteur }}</p>
        <h1>Longueur:</h1>
        <p>{{ longueur }}</p>  
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

But when i generate the printout i didn't find the values of them(it display "None" instead) and there is no error , I do no what I have forgot really!

Here is a picture of the pdf generated.

**it displays the value "None"** on the printout
---> a screenshoot added.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKyB1.png)

please Help me, any help will be appreciated How i can call the values of the fields that i want to display properly.!!?
Thanks in advance.

about the **urls.py**:

```
path('pdf/', views.forms_render_pdf_view, name='pdf_view'),
```

PS: I want to know should i create a method save to save the data of the formular that i have developed to print the fields or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use POST insted of GET

Replace your code from:
`context = {'longuer':request.GET.get('longuer'), 'hauteur':request.GET.get('hauteur')}`

To:

`context = {'longuer':request.POST.get('longuer'), 'hauteur':request.POST.get('hauteur')}`

Or past your html template code for  FormsCreationForm  that submit data to view function (forms_render_pdf_view)

> Update

Another Oops!!
template variable name not equal to model and context data
***longueur != longuer***
replace *longueur* to *longuer* in template

```
 <p>{{ longuer }}</p>
```

Comment: The first solution , I try it already but it's the same result,  the second solution(Or past your html template code for FormsCreationForm that submit data to view function (forms_render_pdf_view)) what do you mean by that , i didn't get you clearly!

Comment: Html code for form that use to enter data,,  this form:: 
« after fill out a form , this form contain the fields "longeur", "hauteur", "element", the user will fill out this form then he will click on a button to display the "moment" and the "area"»

Comment: another issue in generate_pdf.html  , variable name " {{ longueur }} " must be " {{ longuer }} " ... answer updated